# Rails models and const_get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, constants

Given a Rails model `Test` just created in a brand new Rails application:

why can I do following?

`Test::const_get("Test")::const_get("Test")` (for as long as I want)

or the following?

`Test::Test::Test` (for as long as I want)

Comment: Constants defined at the top level are attached to `Object`. e.g. `Object::Test == Test` so `Test::Test` works because `Test` is an `Object` and `Object::Test` is a valid constant. This `Test::Test::Test` should actually warn you that `warning: toplevel constant Test referenced by Test::Test` but that does not make it invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Test::const_get("Test")` returns the Test class (itself) so it's turtles all the way down.

```
puts Test::const_get("Test").class
# Class
puts Test::const_get("Test").is_a? Class
# true
```